# Create New Custom Symbology with QGIS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, symbology, visualisation

I am using QGIS for GIS maps, and data visualization. There are very few symbols available for marker, line and polygons. I want to create my own symbols, that i can later import into QGIS and then use it.

I know that QGIS support XML format for symbols, so any symbol with that XML can be imported into QGIS.

How can i create my own symbol in any software and then export that into QGIS supported format?

There is a way of doing the same thing is ArcMap i.e.. create symbol in **FONTOGRAPHER** and then export it into ArcGIS Support .style file using **Enterprise Architect**, i need to do the same for QGIS.

Comment: You could code/draw your own svg-symbols.

Comment: But SVG does not have support for line symbols

Comment: Can you recommend any good software for drawing ?

Comment: What is a line symbol in your opinion? A line is a line, or a string of symbols to me. Inkscape works fine, or the W3-webeditor

Comment: Okay, I will try Inkscape or W3-webeditor for creating svg.